# How to add custom validation in plugin configuration?

Tags: validation, plugins, configuration, shopware

I have a text field in the configuration section of my plugin. The expected values are numbers separated by ',' eg 1,5,10. User should not be able to set this value to 0. How I can validate the field?

Answer (score 0):

You could hook into the save-event with a subscriber [docs](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/event-guide/)
And there you could access the request data and validate it on your own.

My question would by why do you want to do that?
What do the numbers stand for?